# Not understanding about the sign of Fourier transform of power spectrum

Tags: fourier-transform

I don't understand with the below equations the affirmation that $FT(\Delta(\vec{k})$ is the Fourier transform of $\Delta(\vec{r})$ :

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}{\Delta(\vec{r})=\frac{V}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \int \tilde{\Delta}(\vec{k}) e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} d^{3} \vec{k}} \\ {\tilde{\Delta}(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{V} \int \Delta(\vec{r}) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} d^{3} \vec{r}}\end{array}\right.$$

with the contrast of density :

$$\Delta(\vec{x}) \equiv \frac{\rho(\vec{x})}{\rho_{0}}-1$$

But classicaly, (Forward) Fourier transform is defined by:

$$FT(\Delta(\vec{r}))=\Delta(\vec{k})=\dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\,\int\,\Delta(\vec{r})\,e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\text{d}^3\vec{r}.$$

**So there should be a plus sign at the beginning of post for the first formula** in top image (Inverse Fourier Transform) **and I expect a minus sign for the second formula**. ( I didn't mention also the difference of factors between the 2 formula but this is not my main issue).

Comment: Different authors have different conventions.

Comment: @Qmechanic . Are you sure ? this is important to take the same conventions concerning the definition of power spectrum into cosmology calculus. Which definition do you use personnaly ? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that in my experience, I have found most authors use the minus sign for the forward transform.  However, the important thing is that the forward and inverse Fourier transforms have opposite signs in the exponent; which one is positive and which is negative is ultimately a matter of convention, in the sense that

$$\Delta^+(\vec k) = \int d^3 \vec r  \ \ \Delta(\vec r) e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}$$
and
$$\Delta^-(\vec k) = \int d^3 \vec r  \ \ \Delta(\vec r) e^{-i\vec k \cdot \vec r}$$

contain precisely the same information.  For instance, if $\Delta(\vec r)$ is a real-valued function, then the two transformed functions above are just complex conjugates of one another, so as long as you are consistent in your definitions then you could work with either one.

---

This is similar to the fact that if you transform forward and then backward, you need to include an overall factor of $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}$.  Whether you attach that to the forward transform or the inverse transform, or assign each of them a factor of $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}$, is a matter of convention as well.

Comment: @faya13 Yes, that's right

Comment: Sorry, I rectified my previous comment : thanks for your answer. Indeed, I have done too much signal processing where the spectral analysis is done by transforming time signal with minus sign with Fourier transform. I thought that was the same thing in cosmology since we are interested in "spatial frequencies" of spatial distributions of density contrast.But from what you say, the 2 conventions gives complex conjugates. And what about if the spatial density contrats Δ(⃗ ) is even, that would generate the same 2 real Δ(⃗ ), wouldn't it ?